# DVD drivers for MATSHITADVD-RAM UJ-841S (1.00)

Tags: drivers, mount, dvd

I am new to Ubuntu.  I bought a refurbished Panasonic CF30 with no operating system. I installed Ubuntu and things are working great, except the Matshita DVD player will NOT play DVD's. It recognizes WHAT is in the drive, but I dont see it in the system components or how to set it up to play.
Now as I am typing, I see some pop ups on the side panel, so I will explore if those questions were answered. Thanks.

Comment: Linux doesn't need additional DVD reader drivers. However, it may need additional software to play back (encrypted) video DVDs. I can't tell whether that's you want to do though. Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 3):

The official documentation about playing commercial DVDs can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

You need to install the libdvd-pkg package and follow instructions:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvd-pkg
```

It is not a matter of drivers, it's matter of decryption which isn't shipped with Ubuntu or installed by default due to licensing.

Answer (score 0):

I play DVD's with VLC media player. I do not have a pop-up to automatically play them when they are inserted into the DVD rom. However, if I choose from VLC's menu to play a DVD, then it works great.

You can install VLC from the software center, or by issuing this command:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: thanks....well, I am ALMOST there....it will only play the title page 14 seconds. then stops.  just a blank screen with an orange cone in the middle.

Comment: nowa little closer, i get a message that video is not formated for my region...it is legitimate Movie DVD, and I am in the United States, I think I read something about a 'region setting'.....geez, this is supposed to be preferable over WINDOWS.......arrrgggg

Comment: @L.Cooper In some countries movies and music sells for less than a buck when its over 20 bucks in North America. As such they are "profit margin protected" so they won't play in North America (minus Mexico I guess). That is the philosophy now you need to find out the technical details of what is going wrong...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD_region_code